# Oops! Something Bad Happened, while accessing a documentation

Tags: bug, documentation

After editing a documentation, I got a conflict with an approved change notification, Whenever I try to access the documentation, I get a 500 Internal server error.

Bellow I have attached a Wireshark capture, that contains the requested URL and the HTTP responses.

**Wireshark capture trace :** [image: Wireshark capture trace]

**the error page :**
[image]

Comment: Just blame the bloke in the picture and move on ...

Comment: @rene total savage

Comment: What happens if you try to make an edit to a topic you can't access?  Does that topic become inaccessible too?

Comment: What do you mean by a top that I can't access @br3nt ?

Comment: I meant *can* access.